Issue with Queries Using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED for Community User
I are facing an issue with two queries that are executed by a community user with the WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED clause in the following scenario:

SELECT Id FROM OrgWideEmailAddress
SELECT Id, HTMLValue FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Parts_and_Materials_upload' LIMIT 1

In a normal scenario, these queries work fine; however, when the WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED clause is added, the code does not work as expected.
To resolve this, we have:

Provided access to the OrgWideEmailAddress via a permission set for the community user.
Set the folder containing the EmailTemplate to "This folder is accessible by all users" in Classic email templates.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists.
I would appreciate guidance on how to proceed with using the WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED clause while ensuring security without compromising functionality.
